# spring-data-elasticsearch vs elasticsearch native java api

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-boot

I'm building a project with **elasticsearch** integration in **springboot** 1.4.1. I'm confused as to whether I should use **elasticsearch's 2.4 native java api** or **spring-data-elasticsearch**, wanted to know what is generally recommended and whether there are any pros/cons related to each of them. I will be just using the project to query ES and won't be doing any CRUD operations on the entities.

Comment: What does your project need to do exactly? Will you only be querying ES or also CRUDing some entities?

Comment: I will be just querying ES, won't be doing CRUD operations on the entities

Comment: If you're not doing any CRUD operations then you don't really need spring-data-elasticsearch, the usual client is sufficient.